# Insert if not exist else push into array(as well as update old values) in mongodb php?

Tags: php, mongodb, push, php-mongodb

I ve a mongodb collection in the form of

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50072b17b4a6de3b1100000f")
 "employment_details" : [
 {
         "_id" : ObjectId("50072b17b4a6de3b11000015"),
         "title" : "Information Technology Compliance & Security",
         "rank" : null,
         "department" : null,
         "current" : true,
         "company_id" : ObjectId("5007269fb4a6de941001d19d")
 }
 ]
}
```

What I need is if the "**employment_details**" array is empty or does not exist i need to create and insert new values into the employment_details, else I need to **push** details like this,

```
 { "_id" : ObjectId("50072b17b4a6de3b1100000f")
 "employment_details" : [
 {
         "_id" : ObjectId("50072b17b4a6de3b11000015"),
         "title" : "Information Technology Compliance & Security",
         "rank" : null,
         "department" : null,
         "current" : false,
         "company_id" : ObjectId("5007269fb4a6de941001d19d")
 }
  ......
 {
         "_id" : ObjectId("50072b17b4a6de3b11000018"),
         "title" : "security engineer",
         "rank" : null,
         "department" : null,
         "current" : false,
         "company_id" : ObjectId("5007269fb4a6de941001dasd")
 }
 {
         "_id" : ObjectId("50072b17b4a6de3b11000016"),
         "title" : "software Engineer",
         "rank" : null,
         "department" : null,
         "current" : true,
         "company_id" : ObjectId("5007269fb4a6de94100189e")
 }
]
}
```

But the tricky part is, since i am pushing employment details of a particular employee, the "**current**" field inside the "**employment_details**" must be set **true** only for newly inserted contact, the all other "**current**" field in old **employment_details** must be set **false**, like i mentioned in the above example.

Actually, when a new **employement_detail** is inserted its **current** field must be set **true**, and all other **current** field in previous employment_details must be set to **false**.

I know general syntax for pushing values, but how to update old values and push new values?

Hope I am clear with my question.

Update code(What I've tried):

```
$my_collection->update(
  array("_id"=>$id), 
  array('$push' => 
   array(
     "employment_details" => array("title" => $title, "rank" => $rank, "department" => $dept, "current" => "true", "company_id" => $c_id)
  ))
);
```

But I don't know how to update previous values.

Comment: Is there a little piece of code where you actually tried it?

Comment: $my_collection->update(array("_id"=>$id), array('$push' =>array("employment_details" => array("title" => $title, "rank" => $rank, "current" => "true", "company_id" => $c_id))));

Comment: but I really don't know how to update previous values. @dbf

Comment: Please edit all future requests for code into your original post, already edit this one for you.

Comment: ok. please post answer if you know.

Answer (score 0):

You could first use update to $set all employment_details.current to false and then $push the new record where this field is true.

When you are willing to change your schema, your could do it more elegantly when you change your database schema by having a single object current_employment_detail and an array of past_employment_detail. I don't know your use case, but I would guess that you need the current details more often than the past details. When you have it as an individual field, you are saving an additional search for the employment_detail.current field.

Comment: If possible please help me with the code on setting the current to false and $push new record and moreover I can't change the schema(actually I am not supposed to).

Comment: And also when you set the current to false initially,what if the new employment detail is same as the previous employment detail(i.e. same company_id), in that case we shouldn't push, we should simply update(current = true).

Comment: You need a hook where current value is identical to the new value, if it is identical (no need to push), update to true, else iterate to remove any old values and push all new values. Notice that this is not a 'give me code because I ask for it' site.

Comment: @dbf sorry. didn't get it fully.